# define orderby URL with meta_key=post_views_count

Tags: query-posts, filters, order, views

I want to make an url with meta_key=post_views_count.

E.g: http://www.mysampleweb.com/?meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value&order=DESC

So the posts should be ordered by Views.

Views are counting in the backend - but the url doesn't work. Just orders after newest/oldest posts.

How can I setup this query? Like it is above, it's not working.

Do I have to put something into functions.php - a rewerite Rule?

Thank you!

AD